# Is topological sort of an original graph same as post-ordering dfs of its transpose graph

Tags: graphs, topological-ordering

I have an intuition that topo-sort of an original graph

```
 A -> B -> C
 D -> B
```

topo-sort is  [D, A, B, C]   or  [A, D, B, C]

If I transpose the graph

```
  C -> B -> A   
       B -> D
```

the postordering dfs of this transposed graph also gives  [D, A, B, C]   or  [A, D, B, C]

Please, I can't mathematically prove/disprove it. 
If not true, an counter example would helpful.

> A postordering is a list of the vertices in the order that they were last visited by the algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: Try your claim on your transposed graph, and see if it still makes sense.

Comment: Hi @Yuval Filmus. I showed an example of the transposed graph in the question. I have tried several others, my claim seems to be correct based on my limited cases I tried. I can't find an counter example, and I am not capable of prove it mathematically

Comment: I was suggesting to try your claim not on the graph you give, but on its transposition.

Comment: I try as you suggested. The claim still hold, the topo and dfs order are [C B A D, C B D A]. Do I miss anything?

Comment: If I run DFS on your first graph (this is the transpose of the transposed graph), I get ABCD. After reversing, I get DCBA. This is not a topological ordering for the transposed graph.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I mean post-order DFS. So the post order of first graph is C B A D or C B D A. then I run topo-sort on second graph, it gives me the same orders

Comment: Please update your question to explain what you're doing. We cannot guess your mind. It's even better if you explain what you mean by "post-order DFS", since I've never heard this term.

Comment: https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/topological-sort.html

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph and $G'$ be it's transposed version. Your property follows from the following two facts:

1) The order in which vertices are visited by a postorder visit on $G'$ is the reverse of a topological order $\sigma'$ for $G'$ (in fact, that's a standard way to compute a topological order).
You can see that this is true by noticing that if $(u,v) \in G'$ then $v$ must be visited before $u$ can be visited, i.e., $v$ follows $u$ in $\sigma'$.

2) If $\sigma'$  is a topological order for $G'$, then the linear order $\sigma$ obtained by reversing $\sigma'$ is a topological order for $G$.
You can see that this is true because, for every edge $(u,v)$ of $G$, $G'$ contains $(v,u)$ and therefore $v$ precedes $u$ in $\sigma'$. This means that $(u,v) \in G \implies u$ precedes $v$ in $\sigma$.